# MongoDB format data in an array of objects

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have data on a MongoDB collection stored in documents like these:

```
{
  "_id": "657c54befca2b6a2cdd935ba",
  "data": {
    "name": "Bob",
    "surname": "xxx",
    "age": "20",
  },
  "header": {
    "data": "1702646974156",
  }
  "_class": "Prova"
}
{
  "_id": "657c54befca2b6a2cdd935bb",
  "data": {
    "name": "Tom",
    "surname": "yyy",
    "age": "25",
  },
  "header": {
    "data": "1702646974156",
  }
  "_class": "Prova"
}
```

it is possible through query/aggregate to obtain the data already formatted in an array of objects

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "member": {
          "name": "Bob",
          "surname": "xxx"
      }
    },
    {
      "member": {
          "name": "Tom",
          "surname": "xxx"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Best regards

Comment: I think you can do it using aggregate.look into https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an aggregation like so:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "dataX.member": "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "dataX.member.age"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: "$dataX"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MyjDZD9w-l0) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          "member": {
            "name": "$data.name",
            "surname": "$data.surname"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[See it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7uE-3z8xTmd)